# Allow Apps Access to /data of Other Apps

Tags: storage, android-10, es-file-explorer

I recently moved from ES File Explorer to [MiXplorer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mixplorer.silver&hl=en_US) and discovered that I can't access the /data partition of other apps (`/data/data/com.example.app/`). I can only see `/data/data/com.mixplorer.silver/` with MiXplorer, while ES File Explorer can see everything just fine. I can use Termux to work with files of course, but that's the entire point of having a file explorer. Is there anything I can do?

I'm running DerpFest 10-Official-RMX1921-20200407 (Android 10, April 5th 2020 patch) off of a Realme XT rooted with Magisk 20.4 in case it matters.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- In MX Explorer settings → More settings → check "allow root" . That should prompt request for root
- Check if root rights have been given to MX Explorer in Magisk Superuser (if not check logs, if it had been denied)