# Cannot list all folders in /data/data in few apps

Tags: root-access, file-permissions

I have a rooted Android 11.

Using Termux, or Es File Explorer, I can see all the 284 directories in `/data/data`.

Unfortunately, many file explorer apps (*with* root privileges, such as Total Commander, ZArchiver) can only see 2 folders : `com.google.android.gms` (don't know why), and their own data folder.

I thought this was related to [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/224744/allow-apps-access-to-data-of-other-apps), but apparently no since I granted the root privileges to both apps...

How could I see all the folders in /data/data using (for example) Total Commander?
Doing a `chmod 755` in Termux? Or maybe there is a problem with these apps as if they they don't use root privileges if at least one folder/file is visible in "normal user" mode?

Comment: How do you grant root access to Total Commander / ZArchiver? It works fine Android 10

Comment: In their settings, I selected to read files/folders as root (a pop-up from Magisk asking me if I want to grant - or not - root privileges). They also have a setting "Fix SELinux Context" checked by default, but unchecking this does not seem to solve the issue.

Comment: guess it's related to mount namespaces, the apps does not handle it well. you can set to global in magisk settings for testing purposes

Comment: @alecxs thanks! Did not know about this option (I think the problem of not be able to see folders in `/data/data` is due to an update of magisk - changing some settings). Just tried and it works just as I wanted ! Please consider to write an answer to get more reputation ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To mark this question as solved.

As @alecxs said, these apps does not handle correctly mounting namespaces, and therefore we need to select in Magisk settings `Mount Namespace Mode`->`Global Namespace` instead of Inherit.

Comment: "By default Magisk inherits the calling process's mount namespace. This can be changed in Magisk Manager. If your root app always need global mount access, use --mount-master when calling su. This can be easily done in libsu by adding a flag in config." -- [@topjohnwu](https://twitter.com/topjohnwu/status/1279508461370269696) on Twitter.